# Python List Manipulation With Dates and Columns

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have  a list that has been created as an XML file and looks a bit like this:

```
Jun-30
12036
12345
12535
200
123135
151646
415158
Jul-1
1284646
55464
54645
8464
546544
4654658
```

I am trying to get python to loop through a list like this and transpose it into a CSV friendly format, with the dates at the top of each column. I cannot seem to either get it to recognise the date or transpose the amounts in columns.

Comment: Do all the columns have an equal number of values or does a date signify the beginning of a variable length column?

Comment: Sorry Simeon, you are right. It was created as XML and then converted to CSV.

Comment: Thank you for the resonse Nathan.Actually, In this case the Columns have the same number of values and a loop with a range would be useful. However, with the API I am querying I can see where this will not be the case, so I am trying to figure out a way for a variable list.

Comment: so only possibilities for rows are integers and months?